# Jquery trigger with data passed not working with on and blur

Tags: events, selector, jquery, eventtrigger

I dont know why the blur method is not receiving the passed data when using on and a selector.

Here is the code, just foucs any input, and press tab, and you will see that the isTab parameter is not being setted. Why?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fz5yA/9/

Html:

```
<div id="Container">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var Container = $("#Container");
Container.on({
    keydown : function(e){
        var Item = $(this);

        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if(e.keyCode == 9) {
            Item.trigger("blur",[true]);
            return false;
        }
    },
    blur : function(e, isTab)
    {
        console.log("IsTab:" + isTab);
    }},".Item");

for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    Container.append("<input class='Item'/>");
    Container.append("<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system generated `blur` event just has one argument, not two.  There is no `isTab` argument passed to that event handler in the normal way that the system creates that event.  You can see that in the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

If you change the event name of your manually triggered event to something that isn't the normal `blur` event and you fix the way you are passing the argument in `.trigger()`, then the extra argument will work.  Change to this and you will see the extra argument:

```
Container.on({
    keydown : function(e){
        var Item = $(this);

        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if(e.keyCode == 9) {
            console.log("aaa");
            Item.trigger("myEvent", true);   // Changed event name and fixed the syntax in this line
            return false;
        }
    },
    myEvent : function(e, isTab)             // Changed event name here
    {
        console.log("IsTab:" + isTab);
    }},".Item");
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fz5yA/17/

Comment: So if I want to pass an extra argument to the blur event, is impossible?

Comment: You can, but not from within the keydown event it appears. http://jsfiddle.net/fz5yA/19/ I don't quite understand the *why* part yet. if you remove the trigger code all together, the blur event doesn't get triggered, leading me to expect the parameter to get passed, but it doesn't. The event delegation doesn't have anything to do with the issue either.

Comment: This is really weird!!... the trigger works perfect out the key down event!... but WHY?, is the same code and works different. Do you know why?